# Javascript toggle button with Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, button, toggle

Please does anyone know how to make this toggle button work as per code below.
It only works after the first click and then the button value does not change

http://jsfiddle.net/ossama/2MbsG/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function () {
        fill.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

            if ($(this).attr('value') == 'Top Up') {
                $('#fill').prev('.ui-btn-inner').children('.ui-btn-text').html('Stop');
                $('#fill').buttonMarkup({
                    theme: "c"
                });
            } else {
                $('#fill').prev('.ui-btn-inner').children('.ui-btn-text').html('Stopping');
                $('#fill').buttonMarkup({
                    theme: "b"
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="fill" type="button" data-inline="true" value="Top Up" data-mini="true"
    data-theme="c" />
```

Comment: Do you know the function .toggle()?.. You may be able to create a better solution for this prob?

Comment: I tried the toggle, but i get the same issue mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUYqY/) works as expected I hope:

```
fill.addEventListener("click", function(event)
{
        if ($(this).attr('value') == 'Top Up')
        {
            $(this).val('Stop');
            $(this).prev('.ui-btn-inner').children('.ui-btn-text').html('Stop');
            $(this).buttonMarkup({ theme: "c" });
        }       


       else
        {
            $(this).val('Stopping');
            $(this).prev('.ui-btn-inner').children('.ui-btn-text').html('Stopping');
            $(this).buttonMarkup({ theme: "b" });
        } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what you meant now

Comment: Whilst fiddles are helpful links to fiddles without code are blocked to encourage you to post the code on the site too. Please don't post answers which are nothing more than a reference to a fiddle - you can inline them easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value as you changing HTML of `$(this)` element

```
$(this).val("Stop");
```

your modified code 
http://jsfiddle.net/2MbsG/5/

Comment: your updated jsfiddle does point to my early version? not your updated one?

Answer (score -1):

It works just how how it should.
You don't change it's `value` attribute after each click, so `if` wont go into `else` option.

Comment: -1, it's clear to see what they are attempting. Confirming that their code doesn't work because they did it wrong isn't remotely helpful.

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand the solution you guys are telling me? i replaced wwith $(this).val("Stop"); but the text doesn't change

Comment: I said "It doesn't work because <reason>" and it looks pretty clear to me and abviously to you too.